# Sketch how to export all symbols to file system, while keeping hierarchy

Tags: sketch-app

How do you export all symbols into folders in the file system based on their hierarchy in Sketch?

For example, how do you export this to Top/Long Hair/Straight

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've set up your naming conventions correctly. Now you just have to make sure that your symbols are exportable. Select your symbol artboards and click "make exportable". Then choose the file format of your choice.

[image]

With that done, you should be able to export all the symbols to the destination of your choice and sketch will automatically format them into that folder filing system.

[image]

Hope that helps!